# Where's the global inputrc file in AIX?

Tags: bash, configuration, files, aix, jfs

I want to save my Readline settings globally for all bash users (it is installed on the system), but I cannot find the global configuration path, neither in `/etc` nor in `/usr/etc`. I also couldn't find it on the man pages *myself*.

I think there should be one if there's a local one in `~/.inputrc`

Please help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I think there should be one if there's a local one in ~/.inputrc"

According to documentation, this assumption is wrong. You can have ~/.inputrc for some users without the file /etc/inputrc.

Even worse, /etc/inputrc is read only if there is no .inputrc for a user.

Therefore, if you want to use global settings for all bash users, you have to :

- delete every ~/.inputrc
- create /${PREFIX}/etc/inputrc (where ${PREFIX} is the prefix readline was compiled with).

Source : http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/5.1/postlfs/inputrc.html